# Appending a dictionary of values to a dictionary of lists with same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am given a dictionary of values and a dictionary of lists

```
dict_v = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}
```

&

```
dict_l = {'A': [1,3,4], 'B': [8,5,2], 'C': [4,6,2]}
```

I am trying to append the values of dict_v to the values of dict_l.
So I want it to look like this:

```
{'A': [1,3,4,2], 'B': [8,5,2,3], 'C': [4,6,2,4]}
```

Ive tried the following code:

```
for key in dict_l:
    if key in dict_v:
        dict_v[key]=dict_l[key]+dict_v[key]
    else:
        dict_l[key]=stock_prices[key]
print(dict_v)
```

it's giving me an error message

Comment: Think if this is valid `[1, 2, 3] + 4`? If you want to insert an element to a list use `.append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to a list in this sense like this

```
dict_v = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}
dict_l = {'A': [1,3,4], 'B': [8,5,2], 'C': [4,6,2]}

for key in dict_l:
    if key in dict_v:
        dict_l[key] += [dict_v[key]]
print(dict_l)
```

The change is that you are appending the value `dict_v[key]` as a list `[dict_v[key]]` and appending it to the entries that are already in `dict_l[key]` using `+=`. This way you can also append multiple values as a list to an already existing list.

Answer (score 1):

because you are adding to a list you should user the `append()` method to add to list

```
dict_v = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}
dict_l = {'A': [1,3,4], 'B': [8,5,2], 'C': [4,6,2]}

for key in dict_v.keys():
    dict_l[key].append(dict_v[key])

print(dict_l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
dict_v = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}
dict_l = {'A': [1,3,4], 'B': [8,5,2], 'C': [4,6,2]}
for key in dict_v:
  if key in dict_l:
    temp = dict_l[key]
    temp.append(dict_v[key])
    dict_l[key] = temp
  else:
    dict_l[key] = stock_prices[key]
print(dict_l)
```

So instead of for key in dict_l, I did for key in dict_v just for the sake of logic. I also appended key value from dict_v to dict_l, but in your code you appended the key value from dict_l to dict_v, and I changed that. Hope it helps!